# Why isn't this urlencode JSON GET request working?

Tags: php, json, curl, elasticsearch, get

```
$word = $_GET['search'];
$json = json_encode('{"query":{"match":{"name":"'.$word.'"}}}');
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://10.128.0.2:9200/testers/test/_search' . urlencode($json));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

$word is filled from the URL and this is working normally. $resp isn't coming back with any value. 'name' is the name of elasticsearch field.

I am using PHP to run this curl request [as per elasticserch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) except all in one URL. Are there any better ways to do this from PHP code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a GET call, you need to pass the query in the `source` query string parameter:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://10.128.0.2:9200/testers/test/_search?source=' . urlencode($json));
```